Adding additional fields to TYPO3 extension seminars
I try to add additional fields to the extension seminars (5.7.0) in TYPO3 10.4.34 but they don't show up in the single view in frontend.
What I did so far:

I created the extension my_seminar with the new field precondition.
The field is shown in the backend.

I extended the seminars event model in the file my_seminar/Classes/Domain/Model/Event.php:


namespace MyVendor\MySeminar\Domain\Model;

class Event extends \OliverKlee\Seminars\Model\Event
{
     /**
     * precondition
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $precondition = '';


     /**
     * Returns the precondition
     *
     * @return string $precondition
     */
    public function getPrecondition()
    {
        return $this->precondition;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the precondition
     *
     * @param string $precondition
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPrecondition($precondition)
    {
        $this->precondition = $precondition;
    }
}


I created the hook EventSingleView in the file my_seminar/Classes/Hooks/EventSingleView.php:

namespace MyVendor\MySeminar\Hooks;

use \OliverKlee\Seminars\Hooks\Interfaces\SeminarSingleView;
class EventSingleView implements SeminarSingleView
{

public function modifySingleView(\OliverKlee\Seminars\FrontEnd\DefaultController $controller): void
{
// deprecated
//   $data = $controller->pi_getRecord('tx_seminars_seminars', $controller->piVars['showUid']);
$precondition = $controller->getPrecondition();
$controller->setMarker('PRECONDITION', $precondition);
}


I registered both classes in the file ext_localconf.php:

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['seminars'][\OliverKlee\Seminars\Hooks\Interfaces\SeminarSingleView::class][] = \MyVendor\MySeminar\Hooks\EventSingleView::class; $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\OliverKlee\Seminars\Model\Event::class] =  \MyVendor\MySeminar\Domain\Model\Event::class; 
How can I get the value of $precondition and show it in the marker PRECONDITION?

You are extending the model with a new property precondition and the appropriate setter/getter. Your controller (used in your hook) won't have these... The controller does not have a setMarker()-method.
